# Proper solution for migration of data

Tags: python, web2py

Having problem during migration of database used fake_Migration = false and delete database of mysql, question is i dont want to delete database because it has some important data in it and i want that new field should be added in the tables and with no lost of data and with out any use of fake_Migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Backup MySQL Database + your local 'databases' folder
2. Remove all files from local 'databases' folder
3. `db = DAL(...., fake_migrate_all=True, migrate=False) #This will not perform a real migration but will recreate metadata in your local 'databases' folder`
4. from a python shell, run `python web2py.py -M -S <yourapp>`
5. exit from python shell
6. add new tables/fields in your models
7. `db = DAL(...., fake_migrate_all=False, migrate=True) #To migrate your database structure with the new fields in your model`
8. Run Web2py, and check if your app is OK
9. Once everything is OK, for efficiency you should change `db = DAL(...., fake_migrate_all=False, migrate=True)` into `db = DAL(...., fake_migrate_all=False, migrate=False)` and eventually add `lazy_tables=True` argument. More info here : http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Efficiency-tricks